# Unable to toggle class on onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am trying to learn how to use forms in React.

It is a form with options to select.

On an onclick event, the clicked span tag should change the background color (just to show it was clicked), I am able to achieve this for a single tag but for multiple tags if I click on a single span bg color of both the tags gets changed.

Code:

```
import React from "react";

class MyForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  userClick: true
};
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
}

 handleChange(e) {
  alert(`You selected... ${e.target.textContent}`);
  this.setState({
  userClick: !this.state.userClick
  });
}

handleChange1(e) {
  alert(`You selected... ${e.target.textContent}`);
 this.setState({
  userClick: !this.state.userClick
  });
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="form-mode">
    <h6>Services:</h6>
    <div className="spans">
      <span
        onClick={this.handleChange}
        className={this.state.userClick ? "youClicked" : "unClicked"}
      >
        {" "}
        inPerson{" "}
      </span>
      <span onClick={this.handleChange1} className={this.state.userClick ? "youClicked" : "unClicked"}> Virtual</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
}

 export default MyForm;
```

Comment: It is working fine. it is just that both the listener are changing the same state (which is not recommended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both on click functions are changing the same state variable, `userClick`. If you want the 2 spans to act independently, you'll need two state variables, e.g:

```
handleChange(e) {
  alert(`You selected... ${e.target.textContent}`);
  this.setState({
     firstSpanClick: !this.state.firstSpanClick
  });
}

handleChange1(e) {
  alert(`You selected... ${e.target.textContent}`);
  this.setState({
     secondSpanClick: !this.state.secondSpanClick
  });
}

<span onClick={this.handleChange1} className={this.state.firstSpanClick ? "youClicked" : "unClicked"}> Virtual</span>

<span onClick={this.handleChange2} className={this.state.secondSpanClick ? "youClicked" : "unClicked"}> Virtual</span>
```

A cleaner way of achieving the same outcome would be to name the spans and have one `handleChange`.

```
//Each toggle variable doesn't need to be initialised, this is just for demonstration.

this.state = {
   spanOne: false,
   spanTwo: false
}

handleChange = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.getAttribute('name');
        this.setState({
            [name]: !this.state[name]
        });
    };

<span onClick={this.handleChange} name={'spanOne'} className={this.state.spanOne ? "youClicked" : "unClicked"}> Virtual</span>

<span onClick={this.handleChange} name={'spanTwo'} className={this.state.spanTwo ? "youClicked" : "unClicked"}> Virtual</span>
```

Comment: thanks a lot,it worked. I have a follow up question to it, say if there are multiple options(span tags) , do I need to follow the same practice for each and every span tag or is there something equivalent to getElementsByTagName and running a loop to make the change on which ever is clicked?

Comment: Please see the bottom example, you can just add a different name to the span and use the same handleChange.

Comment: I saw that after making the comment. Thanks.

Comment: If it's a form, i suggest you to use the existing `form` html tag with `input` with type `checkbox`.

You could then use the css selector `input:checked` to add the style you want without defining a state and a `name` attribute for each `span`.

Comment: @amcquaid the second way is not working, there is no toggle effect on onClick.